# ADB not detecting device (but Windows does detect it)

Tags: command-line, android, adb

I have a galaxy A7-2016 running Lineage OS 17.1 and i want to access it using ADB. When I use adb on windows, my phone it showing up however, adb seems to not be working on my computer running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The only ouput I get is

```
List of devices attached
```

I looked for this problem on internet and tried several commands but still not working.

Note :

- I tried using adb with another phone and it's not working too
- I tried doing the plugdev group thing but this did not solve my problem

(sorry for my english)

Thanks for helping

Clement

Comment: What's the "plugdev group thing"?

Comment: @waltinator this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151114/adb-is-not-detecting-my-android-device-on-ubuntu

Comment: @guiverc sorry I mistyped. I am using Ubuntu 20. **04**

Comment: Not an answer, since there are several pieces to the puzzle, in particular: 1. Is the adb package installed? 2. It may depend on the usb options selected after you plug in the android device. 3. There may be no suitable udev rule defined in /usr/lib/udev/rules.d or in /etc/udev/rules.d. Search for adb and udev and rules.

Comment: @Siep So 1 No I did not install adb package because i didn't work so well for me but that does not matter. So I downloaded the zip file with sh scripts. 2 I tried all the options (MIDI, file transfer, photo transfer) my phone was offering but adb still did not detect it.
So I checked both directories... /usr/lib/udev/rules.d has a lot of files (some about persistent storage, others which name contains xorg... some files are also releated to Android but no mention of adb here). In the second /etc directory, the rules.d has 1 file (snap d rules). Is all this normal ?

Comment: It is normal. But /usr/lib/udev/rules.d seems to favor mtp connections. I have a file /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules with a line SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2e04", ATTR{idProduct}=="c025", MODE="0600", OWNER="my_user_name" where idVendor and idProduct can be got from the lsusb output. I assume adb is turned on on your device since it works on windows. But for completeness: go to settings >system > advanced > developer options > on

Comment: @Siep Yes I confirm developer options are turned on. I also tried flushing the fingerprint entries but still not working...